# sparklyr on ec2: can't access spark web interface (4040)

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, sparklyr

I set up a local Spark context using `sparklyr` (`sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.3"`). Connects just fine but can't access the corresponding web interface for some reason. 4040 is open to my IP in the corresponding security group. 
Tried accessing with `http://<ec2 ip>:4040` with no luck. Any known workaround?